# Restrict Camera View in WorldWind Java

Tags: java, camera, worldwind

I've been searching through documentation and examples, but I don't see any good demos showing me what I would like to do:

How do I restrict the view in World Wind Java to a specific region?  As in allowing the user to move the world around, but only through a small area.  Removing the ability to move the camera and setting the view to a specific position would work in my case, but it seems like such a waste of the incredible viewing functionalities of WWJ to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is actually an example of how to do this in gov.nasa.worldwindx.examples (I was only looking through demos): ViewLimits.

One can cast the `WorldWindowGLCanvas`'s view to an `OrbitView`.  Then limits can be applied as such:

```
OrbitView viewbounds = (OrbitView)wwd.getView();
if (viewbounds != null)
{
    OrbitViewLimits limits = viewbounds.getOrbitViewLimits();
    if (limits != null)
    {
        viewLimit = new Sector();// Fill with appropriate bounds
        limits.setCenterLocationLimits(viewLimit);
        limits.setPitchLimits(Angle.fromDegrees(0), Angle.fromDegrees(90));
        //^in degrees downward from looking directly at the earth
        limits.setHeadingLimits(Angle.ZERO, Angle.ZERO);// rotation cw or ccw
        limits.setZoomLimits(minZoom, maxZoom);// in meters
        BasicOrbitViewLimits.applyLimits(viewbounds, limits);
    }
}
```